# Describing borehole information with geojson (javascript)

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, json, borehole

I deal a lot with borehole information and looking the best way to move it around in javascript / take advantage of javascript libraries (e.g. leaflet) for looking at this information on mobile devices / maps.  I'm most interested in the popup/mouseover actions to describe additional data contained within a point.

In plan, these are points.  In reality, it's a line I am looking at end on with a number of data points stacked in the same x,y location.

For example 
Point 1 (x,y,z collar location): 

`+------------+-----------+---------+
| Depth from | Depth to  | Reading |
+------------+-----------+---------+
| 0          | 2         | 4       |
| 2          | 4         | 7       |
| 4          | 7         | 15      |
+------------+-----------+---------+`

etc.

Is there a good way to capture the above using geojson?  Currently I parse a lot of it in JSON (or multidimensional arrays) in javascript.  I can shoe-horn it into geojson by making many depth parameters, but it's pretty awkward (and even more awkward when I have multiple different types of data at varying depths along the same hole).

What does everyone use for borehole data and leaflet/other sources? Looking for advice / a point in the right direction, as the direction I'm going is defining my own internal format and writing my own scripts for populating the downhole information in tables during mouse-overs (which is time consuming).

Comment: You're basically talking about doing [dynamic segmentation](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Dynamic%20segmentation) along the Z axis. Interesting. However, I'm not sure you really want to treat the borehole itself as a linear feature, but rather as a `Point` feature that has associated depth data stored in the `properties`.

Answer (score 2):

The cool thing about geoJson is the flexibility of the `properties`. So if you already have an object to represent the depths (ie: an array of depth intervals with readings) you can just attach this info to the GeoJson object. To use this in a map you just need to create an association (such as `x,y`) between the depth readings and the point on the surface.)

JSON:

```
var boreData = { 
  "SurfacePoint": [-117, 46], 
  "DepthReadings": [
    {"From": 0, "To": 2, "Reading": 4}, 
    {"From": 2, "To": 4, "Reading": 7 }, ... 
   ] 
}
```

GeoJSON:

```
var geoJsonFeature = {
 "type": "Feature", "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": boreData.SurfacePoint
  },
  "properties": boreData
}
```

Define what happens on click of the surface feature:

```
function clickFeature(e)
{
   var data = e.target.feature.properties;

   // do your cool and creative visualization of the borehole   
   alert(JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

Add marker (layer) for the surface point where drilling began (simplified this a bit, but you get the idea..):

```
        function onEachFeature(feature, layer)
        {
            layer.on({
                click: clickFeature
            });
        }

        var layer = L.geoJson(geoJsonFeature, {
            onEachFeature: onEachFeature
        });
```

Usage: Click on the borehole surface marker to view the details for the borehole. To visualize it you can even do some cool stuff like scaling the data into a stacked bar chart or something, whatever suits your fancy...